# how to fix firebase "command not found" error

Tags: firebase

Hi I have this problem when attempting to add `firebase` package, getting the error below...

```
found 385 vulnerabilities (366 low, 7 moderate, 12 high)
  run `npm audit fix`` to fix them, or `nom audit` for details
PS D: \Downloads\ codecanyon-G8bOFJ14-superstore-grocery-store-super-shop-management-pos\main-files\superstore-1.1> firebase init functions
firebase: The term 'firebase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ firebase init functions
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (firebase:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image: attached-screenshot]

Comment: Add the error message text to the question.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you didn't install the Firebase CLI yet.

If you have NPM installed locally, you can install the Firebase CLI with:

```
npm install firebase-tools -g
```

Or you can use the [pre-built binary for Windows](https://firebase.tools/bin/win/instant/latest) that's linked from the [installation instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-windows). If you're not too comfortable with NPM yet, I recommend this as an easier way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

1. npm config get prefix
2. In my case it returns a path C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local. In your case it may be return different path. Then go to the path and find node_modules -> npm and then copy the path.
3. Go to path C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\npm
4. Clikedit the system environment variable
5. Click environment variable
6. From the bottom system variable find the path
7. click edit in the path variable
8. Click new and paste the path point 3 in my case
9. Finally click ok and close command line
10. Reopen command line and type firebase --version. It will then return the version you have install.